# how to get string after id= untill the first double quote in big php string?

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all

hi all i am trying to parse a big string and want to obtain only the value of id(id=dfsdfdsfdsfsaddfdfdfd) . My current code output extra data beyon the id value. could any one help me fix this problem.Thanks

```
preg_match_all("#live3.me.somesite.com([^<]+)\"#", $html, $foo);
print_r($foo[0]);
```

sample input string:

```
$html=".............."url":"rtmp:\/\/live3.me.somesite.com\/live\/?id=dfsdfdsfdsfsaddfdfdfd","name":"8.low.stream".........";
```

Comment: If you're id is always going to be preceded by a question mark and always end with a double quote, than try this: http://3v4l.org/sEDfP. If not, please be more specific.

Comment: What kind of data (format) contains exactly `$html`?

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue where you are set on using preg_match?

Or would something like 'parse_url' be acceptable?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
Once parsed, getting specific query string parameters out should be easy

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of answering an 8 month old question, here is my go at it :-)

We have got this to work with:

```
$html='".............."url":"rtmp:\/\/live3.me.somesite.com\/live\/?id=dfsdfdsfdsfsaddfdfdfd","name":"8.low.stream"........."';
```

That string sure looks a bit JSONish to me, so why not ...

```
// 1. Get rid of leading and trailing quotes and dots
$clean = trim($html, '"');
$clean = trim($clean, '.');

// 2. Add squiggly brackets to form a JSON string
$json = '{' . $clean . '}';

// 3. Decode the JSON into an array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// 4. Parse URL value from the array and grab the query part
$query = parse_url($array['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

// 5. Get parameter values from the query
parse_str($query, $params);

// 6. Ta-da!
echo "Readable : ", $params['id'], PHP_EOL;
```

And of course ...

```
// The one-liner!
parse_str(parse_url(json_decode('{'.trim(trim($html,'"'),'.').'}', true)['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $params2);
echo "One-liner: ", $params2['id'], PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Readable : dfsdfdsfdsfsaddfdfdfd
One-liner: dfsdfdsfdsfsaddfdfdfd
```